# Use StreamSocket to transfer files and receive wrong data (UWP)

Tags: c#, file, sockets, uwp

In my project, I use **StreamSocket** to send files and **StreamSocketListener** to receive files in LAN. But when I tested, my received file size is less than the file I sent.(For example, my sent file size are about 100M and received file size are just 2-3M)

I am very very confused, here are my code, tks.

Send Code (file is **StorageFile**, item is my custom class)

```
var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
var fileInputStream = fileStream.AsInputStream();

StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
HostName serverHost = new HostName(item.Address);
string serverPort = item.Port;
await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);

uint capacity = 10000000;
Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(capacity);

// Send some heads
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync("file");
await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(file.Name);
await streamWriter.FlushAsync();

var outputStream = socket.OutputStream;

while (true)
{
    await fileInputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);

    if (buffer.Length > 0)
    {
        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

streamWriter.Dispose();
outputStream.Dispose();
socket.Dispose();
```

Receive Code (Event is **StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived**)

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
string head = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();

string fileName = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();

StorageFile file = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
var inputStream = args.Socket.InputStream;

uint capacity = 10000000;
Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(capacity);

if (file != null)
{
    CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);

    while (true)
    {
        await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);

        if (buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    FileUpdateStatus updateStatus = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
}
```

Comment: You should check return value of the ReadAsync method instead of checking buffer.Length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question just now. In receive code, I use **await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);** to write buffer to file. This method can't append buffer to file. So I use **OutputStream.WriteAsync()** to deal with it.